# Parsing XML in JAVA SAX, without populating default attributes

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am trying to parse a given XML against a DTD using javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser. But, I just dont want default attributes to get populated based on DTD. So I tried the setFeature of SAXParserFactory as described in http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#nonvalidating.load-dtd-grammar:

```
SAXParserFactory fact = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
fact.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
```

But, it does not seem to work! I still get the output with default attributes populated! Could you please let me know on how to fix this?

Comment: I have updated my original question. Earlier the value of load-dtd-grammar was set to true; it was a typo, my mistake! The program does not work whatever value (true/false) I set to this feature.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the xerces parser?

Comment: Finally I wrote my own parser for this purpose, and it works well. Probably I will put it in github/sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer just in front of your eyes. From the link you share:

> True: Load the DTD and use it to add default attributes and set
> attribute types when parsing.
>
> False: Build the grammar but do not
> use the default attributes and attribute types information it
> contains.

So you should run it with that feature set to false:

```
SAXParserFactory fact = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); fact.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, the program does not work whatever value (true/false) I set to it. Also, actually in my question I wanted to present it with load-dtd-grammar set to "false", but I mistakenly put it as "true". Sorry for the confusion. Like I said, the program does not work with whatever value I set to it.